# how can i access scanner and scan document using java, jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, scanning

How can i access scanner and scan document using java, jquery or javascript.Please give me a solution..

I have tried with aspire scanner.js .But while using with chrome version 42, it shows like no longer support java extention.

I would like to implement scanning for web applications.

Please let me know if there any solution..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different language.

Comment: yeah i know..But my ultimate aim is to detect a scanner in client side..So for that it will better to use javascript or jquery na?After scanning from client side ,the scanned document should saved in server.For that it will better to use java.Leave the java part.I just want a code to detect scanner in  my app..Please help me.

Comment: Try Dynamic Web TWAIN SDK for accessing scanners in JavaScript Online demo: http://www.dynamsoft.com/Demo/DWT/online_demo_scan.aspx

Comment: Be warry of these JS libraries that require apps to be installed; they are a security liability.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome 42 is supported by [Scanner.js](http://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/direct-to-server-php-asp.net-overview.html). You may try out scanner.js's [html5/JavaScript web browser based scanning demo](http://asprise.com/document-scan-upload-image-browser/javascript-web-scanner.js-demos.html) here.

Scanner.js supports both [NPAPI browsers (like Chrome 44 and lower, IE, Firefox, Opera) and Non-NPAPI browsers (Chrome 45+, Edge)](http://asprise.com/scan/scannerjs/docs/html/intro-scannerjs-sdk-library.html#browsers-supported).

When running Scanner.js from NPAPI browsers, it attempts to use a Java applet so that no software is required to install. As for non-NPAPI browsers, scan app is required.

Comment: But the biggest disadvantage of Scanner.js is, it does not work on Linux and Mac systems at all. Windows freak!

Comment: Support for more OS will be added under one condition: there is enough demand.

Comment: I feel that it goes hand in hand. If you feature it, demand will automatically overwhelm.

Comment: How about the license of Asprise scanner.js is it open source

Comment: from their website it costs between $3,000 to $130,000 depending on the option you choose

Comment: Dynamic Web TWAIN supports Linux and Mac systems. @Srk95

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make JavaScript work for scanning documents:

- JavaScript API provided by web browser. For example, in ChromeOS, you can easily use JavaScript API to access scanner.
- Establish a communication mechanism between scanner service and web client JavaScript API. For example, Dynamic Web TWAIN runs a service to access document scanners and transfer document images to JavaScript via websocket.